# python / networkx find the distance from root

Tags: python, networkx

I have the following example

```
import networkx as nx

data = {
  'modules': {
         'aws_vpc': {
            'deps': []
         },
         'aws_security_group': {
           'deps': ['aws_vpc']
         },
         'aws_subnet': {
            'deps': ['aws_vpc']
         },
         'aws_db_subnet': {
            'deps': ['aws_subnet']
         },
         'aws_db_instance': {
            'deps': ['aws_security_group','aws_db_subnet']
         }
   }
}


G = nx.DiGraph()
roots = set()
for module,data in data['modules'].items():
    if len(data['deps']) == 0:
        roots.add(module)
        continue

    for d in data['deps']:
        G.add_edge(d, module)


for s in roots:
    print s
    spacer = {s: 0}
    for prereq, target in nx.dfs_edges(G, s):
        spacer[target] = spacer[prereq] + 2
        print '{spacer}+-{t}'.format(
                                     spacer=' ' * spacer[prereq],
                                     t=target)
    print ''
```

Right now it looks like

```
aws_vpc
+-aws_security_group
  +-aws_db_instance
+-aws_subnet
  +-aws_db_subnet
```

What I want to do is find the current distance from the root module from a dependancy. So for example. aws_db_instance depends on aws_security_group and aws_db_subnet.

aws_db_subnet is further away so it should add aws_db_instance to the edge there. I just can't figure out a way to find the distance from a module's dependancies.

I'm aware that graphs don't always behave as trees so maybe I'm using the wrong module but the idea is you could have many roots that don't have any dependancies. So I thought networkx would be a good fit.

So the end result should look like

```
aws_vpc
+-aws_security_group
+-aws_subnet
  +-aws_db_subnet
    +-aws_db_instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [nx.shortest_path](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html)?

```
distance = len(nx.shortest_path(G, source='aws_vpc', target='aws_subnet'))
```

Comment: thanks I get `networkx.exception.NetworkXError: The node aws_vpc is not in the digraph.` so I must be creating the paths wrong

Comment: @Mike Try to vizualize the graph: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; nx.draw_networkx(g); plt.show()` Maybe the `source` and `target` are reversed.

Comment: not sure what I did but its now working.. thanks for the quick answer